# Closing a keyboard

Tags: xcode, button, keyboard, ibaction

I use this way of closing a keyboard in my MainViewController and it works perfectly.

```
-(IBAction)closeKeyboard {
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But if I use the same in another ViewController with is pushed in from the MainViewController it does not work.
I connect it to a button for closing the keyboard.
How to change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another interesting method:

```
[anyView endEditing:YES];
```

Like this all textfield from your view resignFirstResponder

Comment: It does not work, but probably I put these lines in wrong place

Comment: Now I have tried your method and reading up about it, thanks. But I must admit my mistake in the question and know why it did not work. A very simple answer. I forgot to connect the textfield. Embarrassing.